# cannot appear in a constant expression

Tags: c++, constructor, constant-expression, constructor-overloading

In the following c++ programm:

```
class matrix {
public:
  int n;
  double **x;

  matrix(int n) : n(n) { 
    x=new double[n][n]; 
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
       for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
       {
         x[i][j]=0;
       }
    }
 }
 ...
```

I get the following error: "'n' cannot appear in a constant-expression".
Since im relatively new to cpp i dont really know why this error occurs (especially because i did almost the exact same thing with a class called vector and there it was no problem at all) and how to fix it.
I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this expression

```
x=new double[n][n];
```

all dimensions except the leftmost shall be constant expressions.

The correct approach is

```
x = new double *[n];
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) x[i] = new double[n];

for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{ 
   for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
     x[i][j]=0;
   }
}
```

Or if your compiler supports C++ 2011 then it can be done simpler without explicit initialization in the loops

```
x = new double *[n];
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) x[i] = new double[n] {};
```

Comment: Also don't forget to release the memory

Comment: In C++11 : `auto arr = new double[n][n]();`

Comment: For a *matrix*, you should probably *not* use an array of pointers, but a contiguous section of memory.

Comment: @P0W You are wrong. auto arr = new double[n][n](); is not valid in C++11 because the rightmost expression must be a constant expression.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Did I said something, that it should, I just wrote that it can be done using that statement, of course it must be a `const` Intention was to show `()` usage for initialization without for loop